# HTTP PUT with RestKit 0.10.1 and simple return type

Tags: ios6, restkit

I have a REST method at `http://api.mysite/RestMethod?uid=1` that accepts `Credentials` object in the body of the request. `Credentials` object is pretty simple: has two properties, `UserName` and `Password`. After successfull request the method returns an integer.

I want to put Credentials to the above `URL` and get back the returned integer value. All the examples out there show `PUT` when request and response both work with the same type object. How would I get back an `int`?

I was able to get `PUT` working using

```
[objectManager putObject:credentials delegate:self];
```

RestKit shows that response came back with Status Code 200. But it fails to deserialize the integer.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm in no way required to use RestKit. I will consider other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up rewriting my API method to return same `Credentials` object with a boolean flag `IsAuthenticated` set to either true or false, and used `RKObjectManager` mappings to map serializers/deserializers to the JSON